# How to configure NHibernate to use connection string from <connectionStrings> configuration section

Tags: nhibernate

does anybody know how to configure NHibernate properties file to use a connection string already specified in  configuration element?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I found it on google.com:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="connection_string_name" connectionString="[connection string]"/>
</connectionStrings>

<hibernate-configuration xmlns="urn:nhibernate-configuration-2.2">
    <session-factory>
        ...
        <property name="connection.connection_string_name">connection_string_name</property>
        ...
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```