# How to load application settings to NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration object?

Tags: nhibernate, app-config, configurationmanager

How to load application settings to `NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration` object by using `System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager` from App.config?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

app.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="Northwind" connectionString=
       "Data Source=(local);Initial Catalog=Northwind;Trusted_Connection=True;>
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

C# code:

```
string connectionString =  System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager
                                 .ConnectionStrings["Northwind"].ToString();

NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration nHibernateConfiguration =
                                      new NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration();
nHibernateConfiguration.SetProperty(
  NHibernate.Cfg.Environment.ProxyFactoryFactoryClass,
  typeof(NHibernate.ByteCode.Castle.ProxyFactoryFactory).AssemblyQualifiedName);
nHibernateConfiguration.SetProperty(
  NHibernate.Cfg.Environment.Dialect,
  typeof(NHibernate.Dialect.MsSql2005Dialect).AssemblyQualifiedName);
nHibernateConfiguration.SetProperty(
  NHibernate.Cfg.Environment.ConnectionString, connectionString);
nHibernateConfiguration.SetProperty(
  NHibernate.Cfg.Environment.FormatSql, "true");
nHibernateConfiguration.AddAssembly(Assembly.GetCallingAssembly());

ISessionFactory oneISessionFactory = nHibernateConfiguration
                                        .BuildSessionFactory();
```

Comment: Instead of doing the manual labor of getting the value from the configuration manager, try setting `connection_string_name`. See [How to configure NHibernate to use connection string from <connectionStrings> configuration section](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/455664/how-to-configure-nhibernate-to-use-connection-string-from-connectionstrings-co) and @LachlanRoche's answer.

Comment: @Joel: Did you read the question before downvoting me?  It specifically calls out System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.  Lachlan's answer is helpful, but it doesn't answer the question that was asked.

Comment: Considering that NHibernate uses `ConfigurationManager` too, its not very (cross-project) DRY to rewrite that same piece of functionality.

Answer (score 25):

The hibernate configuration can also be moved into app.config, which simplifies the startup code. See section [XML Configuration File](http://nhibernate.info/doc/nh/en/index.html#configuration-xmlconfig) in the NHibernate reference manual.

```
Configuration cfg = new NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration();
ISessionFactory sf = cfg.Configure().BuildSessionFactory();
```

And in app.config:

```
<configuration>
        <configSections>
            <section name="hibernate-configuration" type="NHibernate.Cfg.ConfigurationSectionHandler, NHibernate" />
        </configSections>
        <hibernate-configuration xmlns="urn:nhibernate-configuration-2.2">
            <session-factory>
                <property name="connection.provider">NHibernate.Connection.DriverConnectionProvider</property>
                <property name="connection.dialect">NHibernate.Dialect.MsSql2005Dialect</property>
                <property name="connection.connection_string_name">Northwind</property>
                <property name="proxyfactory.factory_class">NHibernate.ByteCode.LinFu.ProxyFactoryFactory, NHibernate.ByteCode.LinFu</property>
                <mapping assembly="assemblyname" />
            </session-factory>
        </hibernate-configuration>
        <connectionStrings>
                <add name="Northwind" connectionString="Data Source=(local);Initial Catalog=Northwind;Trusted_Connection=True;>
        </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

Comment: xmlns="urn:nhibernate-configuration-2.2" in the <hibernate-configuration> is very important. I didn't have it, and kept getting error. Thank you @Lachlan_Roche